# Any code/library to scale down an UIImage?

Tags: iphone, graphics

Is there any code or library out there that can help me scale down an image? If you take a picture with the iPhone, it is something like 2000x1000 pixels which is not very network friendly. I want to scale it down to say 480x320. Any hints?

Comment: Why do you want to scale it? Is it just for display or upload?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I am using. Works well. I'll definitely be watching this question to see if anyone has anything better/faster. I just added the below to a category on `UIimage`.

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
  UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return newImage;
}
```

Comment: so what happens if the ratio is different? what will drawInRect do? Say original is 2000x1000 and I passed in 480x480

Comment: From the developer docs on UIImage - "Draws the entire image in the specified rectangle, scaling it as needed to fit."

Comment: This method takes a LONG time to run, sometimes more than a minute. I'm scaling down the picture taken by the iPhone 3GS camera to 500x500. Why is that I wonder?

Comment: I have noticed that it takes a while (but for me, it's 4-8 seconds, rather than over minute) which was why I was watching the other answers... I intend to benchmark them.

Comment: Why is is that it takes < 1 second to scale a picture into a UIImageView, but so many seconds to scale it into another UIImage?

Answer (score 2):

See http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/ - this has a set of code you can download as well as some descriptions.

If speed is a worry, you can experiment with using CGContextSetInterpolationQuality to set a lower interpolation quality than the default.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, this is NOT my code. I did a little digging and found it [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5204-resize-image-high-quality.html#post23898). I figured you'd have to drop into the CoreGraphics layer, but wasn't quite sure of the specifics. This should work. Just be careful about managing your memory.

```
//  ==============================================================
//  resizedImage
//  ==============================================================
// Return a scaled down copy of the image.  

UIImage* resizedImage(UIImage *inImage, CGRect thumbRect)
{
    CGImageRef          imageRef = [inImage CGImage];
    CGImageAlphaInfo    alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    // There's a wierdness with kCGImageAlphaNone and CGBitmapContextCreate
    // see Supported Pixel Formats in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide
    // Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context section
    // only RGB 8 bit images with alpha of kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst,
    // and kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, with a few other oddball image kinds are supported
    // The images on input here are likely to be png or jpeg files
    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

    // Build a bitmap context that's the size of the thumbRect
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                NULL,
                thumbRect.size.width,       // width
                thumbRect.size.height,      // height
                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),   // really needs to always be 8
                4 * thumbRect.size.width,   // rowbytes
                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                alphaInfo
        );

    // Draw into the context, this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, thumbRect, imageRef);

    // Get an image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef  ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage*    result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);   // ok if NULL
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution I posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees/1317194#1317194). The question involves rotating an image 90 degrees instead of scaling it, but the premise is the same (it's just the matrix transformation that is different).