# Creating a UIImage from a scaled and rotated UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, scaling

I'm working on an app whose functionality is, among other things, panning, scaling and rotating images. At first I implemented all the gesture recognition being applied to the UIImageView of the picture, then I noticed that the actual image remained the same - and I needed it to be modified.

I found a question on SO dealing with this sort a problem - [Creating a UIImage from a rotated UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856556/creating-a-uiimage-from-a-rotated-uiimageview) - and I was actually able to use the code Magic Bullet Dave provided. However, as my app is supposed to support not only rotation but also scaling of the image I had to modify it. He basically wrote a method to return a CGRect in which the rotated image would fit. The problem is I'm not able to scale said CGRect to enclose the scaled image properly. When I rotate the image in the app (run in simulator) and then observe a png version saved for testing purposes, the CGRect clips the top and bottom corners of the image - the closer the image is to being rotated 90 degrees, the more of it is clipped.

This is the method returning the CGRect:

```
- (CGRect) getBoundingRectAfterRotation: (CGRect) rectangle byAngle: (CGFloat) angleOfRotation {

    // Calculate the width and height of the bounding rectangle using basic trig
    CGFloat newWidth = rectangle.size.width * fabs(cosf(angleOfRotation)) + rectangle.size.height * fabs(sinf(angleOfRotation));
    CGFloat newHeight = rectangle.size.height * fabs(cosf(angleOfRotation)) + rectangle.size.width * fabs(sinf(angleOfRotation));

    // Calculate the position of the origin
    CGFloat newX = rectangle.origin.x + ((rectangle.size.width - newWidth) / 2);
    CGFloat newY = rectangle.origin.y + ((rectangle.size.height - newHeight) / 2);

    // Create the new rectangle
    CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
    return CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rotatedRect, CGAffineTransformScale(originalState, theScale, theScale));
}
```

As you can see, I try to get the CGRect for the rotated image and scale it - to no avail.
That is then used in creating the actual image:

```
CGFloat angle = totalAngle;
UIImage *viewImage;

// Get image width, height of the bounding rectangle
CGRect boundingRect = [self getBoundingRectAfterRotation: self.photoView.bounds byAngle:angle];

// Create a graphics context the size of the bounding rectangle
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(boundingRect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Rotate and translate the context
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, boundingRect.size.width/2, boundingRect.size.height/2);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angle);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, theScale, -theScale);

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
```

The code isn't cleaned up yet as this is clearly not finished - currently I made a workaround by making the CGRect bigger than necessary, though I would like to avoid this of course.

Any help is welcome.