# Do I need to release CGColorSpaceRef under ARC?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRGB = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(context, colorSpaceRGB);
CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, colorSpaceRGB);
```

After that I do some drawing. When I'm done,
do I need to manually release `colorSpaceRGB` if I'm using ARC? Like this:

```
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRGB);
```

Or I don't need to do anything?

Thanks :)

Comment: This answer explains well why and when need to release any object. Please check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21967681/2849443

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  According to Apple's doc:  Because CGColorSpaceRelease function is equivalent to CFRelease, except that it does not cause an error if the cs parameter is NULL.
And if you create, copy, or explicitly retain a Core Foundation object, you are responsible for releasing it when you no longer need it (see Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation).

Comment: On a side note, this is not necessary (and not possible) under Swift.

Answer (score 10):

Update for Swift 4.0:

This is no longer needed in current versions of Swift.

```
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace)
```

This line of code now gives the following message:

'CGColorSpaceRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe so, even under ARC.

You need to call `CGColorSpaceRelease` as per the documentation [CGColorSpace Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html).