# Iphone app crash when releasing CGColorSpaceRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, color-space

I am using `CGColorSpaceRef` and when i release it, its crash.
The Way i creates it and release

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
```

After doing some task and then release

```
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

error shown by compiler is
"Assertion failed: (!state->is_singleton), function color_space_state_dealloc, file ColorSpaces/CGColorSpace.c, line 127"
And strange thing is happend when i not release colorspace or just set to nil its work fine, I don't know why this happen.
Please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.
Have a happy day.

Comment: We've to release this as apple docs mentioned : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html

Comment: `CGColorSpaceRelease` is correct after `CGColorSpaceCreateXXX`. So the problem must be in what you do between these calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have over released the `colorspace` object.  I have just run the following program and I get the error message you quoted.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    }
}
```

This `SIGABRT`s with the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (!state->is_singleton), function color_space_state_dealloc, file ColorSpaces/CGColorSpace.c, line 127.
```

If I only call `CGColorSpaceRelease` once the program compiles and runs without error.

The static analyser (Shift-Cmd-B) may well be able to show you were you've gone wrong. It certainly flags the above code with "Reference counted object is used after it is released" on the second `CGColorSpaceRelease` call.

Comment: agreed with you! Problem is when its being called again and again but is there any way that i can find retain counter on Colorspace so that its = 0 then i'll not release colorspace?

Comment: You can use `CFGetRetainCount(colorspace)` to get the retain count, HOWEVER, you should see https://web.archive.org/web/20160111073519/http://whentouseretaincount.com/ before you use this (don't forget to scroll down).  The issue you will have is that the retain count of the `colorspace` variable immediately after being created is 2, after the release it is 1 but if you release it again you'll get the error.

Comment: Given the posts that Nenad has found you may just have to not release `colorspace` and live with the memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually responsible for retaining and releasing the color space if/as necessary! I.e. if you need to, retain it. If you don't need to retain, don't release! See the docs for more on this topic: [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)

**Update:**

Regarding the wired error our poster enecountered above, take a look at ddopsons posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273291/1126955). Unfortunately there's no solution provied, but a possible workaround instead.

Comment: A device-dependent RGB color space. You are responsible for releasing this object by calling CGColorSpaceRelease. If unsuccessful, returns NULL.
See this link  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html

Comment: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB Increment retain count!

Comment: @Nenad Mihajlovic I'm not sure what point you are trying to make.  The document you reference says that you own objects returned by functions with `create` in the name.  `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` has create in the name.  So, the OPs assumption that they need to release the color space seems correct.

Comment: Indeed, the OPs assumption is right, which makes my answer maybe pointless! But i started searching for this strange error the OP has and found the following [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9273291/1126955). Scroll down to ddopsons answer and take a look at the links.

Comment: @NenadMihajlovic Nice find! Perhaps you should update your original answer with reference to your discovery :)

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to release a constant value.  Cant do that

Comment: This is mentioned on apple doc that it should be release. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @stackmonster If you are correct that the returned value is a constant then the `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` function is not following Apple's Core Foundation memory management rules.  Can you provide a reference as to why you believe it is a constant?

Comment: yeah its in your error message: Assertion failed: (!state->is_singleton),

Comment: @stackmonster That simply suggests the returned object may be a singleton.  Even if it is a singleton, calling `CGColorSpaceRelease` should effectively be a noop.  It seems unlikely that Apple would write a library that crashes if you try to release the object given the memory management rules (create in the function name) and the fact the documentation for `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` specifically says "You are responsible for releasing this object by calling CGColorSpaceRelease."

Comment: how is an NSAssertionFailure a "noop"?