# How to rotate image file?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, file, rotation

How can I easily rotate image file saved in documents directory?

I'm saving it with code:

```
(...)
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 1.0);
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[imageData writeToFile:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.jpg"] atomically:NO];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily accomplished using `CGContextRotateCTM()`:

Found in a SO answer here: [How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}
- (UIImage*) rotateImage:(UIImage*)src rotationDirection:(UIImageOrientation)orientation {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(-90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    }

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
```

Comment: This isn't even really a Obj-C method.. I tried making something out of it but it didn't rotate anything in this case.

Comment: It's an easily callable function. But, if you prefer a method, no problem. I've changed the code to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry, I was checking similar function code before and had multiple syntax errors. I tried CGContextRotateCTM before but didn't do anything, will try your solution in a bit, thanks!