# Rotate an jpg on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an app that takes the photos via the camera or select it from the library and save it as jpg in the documents folder. But before saving it, I would like to rotate is by 90degrees.

Hope anyone can help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 4 and later:
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW37)

For iOS 3 and previous:
[How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}
UIImage* rotate(UIImage* src, UIImageOrientation orientation)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(-90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    }

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Available in iOS 4.0 and later. Need it for 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) {return degrees * M_PI/180;}
UIImage* rotate(UIImage* src, UIImageOrientation orientation)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(-90));
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, radians(90));
    }

    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)

Answer (score 0):

```
img.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265/2);
```