# Splash Screen Image's orientation is not correct

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, splash-screen

I want to use custom splash screen so I am doing this in my app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    homeNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

    [homeNavigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:homeNavigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self animateSplash];

    return YES;
}

- (void)animateSplash {

    CGRect cgRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize cgSize = cgRect.size;

    // set default portrait for now, will be updated if necessary
    NSString *imageName = @"splash_screen.png";
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, cgSize.width, cgSize.height );

    imageStage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    imageStage.frame = imageFrame;


    [window addSubview:imageStage];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:imageStage];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:2];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];

    imageStage.alpha = 0.0f;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    // remove and clean up splash image view
    [imageStage removeFromSuperview];
    [imageStage release];
    imageStage = nil;

}
```

This work ok but as my app is Launches in Landscape (Home button right) mode my splash image orientation is not setting correctly.

Comment: Please read the FAQ before posting; special points of interest for you: 1. code formatting, 2. using footers.

Comment: Sure will do that Till I am new to StackOverflow :( will take care from the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an image that is rotated to look correct in your orientation.

If you really want to do it in code for some reason, check out [How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees) for different ways to rotate a UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell iOS that you want to launch your app in Landscape mode. You can follow the directions from Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) to achieve this.

Comment: That I have already stated in my plist still my image is not rotated correctly with the screen

Comment: Do you have set to LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight?