# Xcode: How to get UIImage after UIImageView rotated?

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, rotation, uiimage

I use the code below to rotate UIImageView (only rotate 90degrees).

```
degrees = 0;

- (IBAction)processRotate:(id)sender {

     float radians = degrees / 57.2958;

     imageView.center = CGPointMake(160, 180);

     imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);

     degrees += 90;

     if(degrees == 360){

         degrees = 0;
     }  

}
```

How can I get the UIImage with the current imageView?
Any help is very appreciative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to get a rotated UIImage from the UIImageView, after you have applied a transform to the latter? Then this is not going to work as you are applying the transform to the UIImageView and not the UIImage. If you want to rotate the UIImage you should do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees).