# How to change Rotation of image after taking in Landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I'm working on PocketWallet application in which I'm taking any type of card rear and front images and then save them in Database. My problem is that when I take image in portrait mode the rotation of images showing well in my resulting view. But when I take image in landscape mode then the images rotate in 90 degrees. How can I set the rotation of the image in portrait mode after taking in landscape.
I'm using UIimagePickerCamera for taking image.
please help me......thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out if your image was taken in landscape mode, take a look at the `imageOrientation` property of UIImage. The `UIImagePickerCamera` will set that flag correctly. It sounds like your app simply needs to make a correction to it. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees) gives you a method for how to do that.