# UITapGestureRecognizer to detect single touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have 2 imageview, and I want them to rotate when they are clicked. This is my code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognizerMethod:)];
```

Then in the `tapRecognizerMethod`:

```
- (void)tapRecognizerMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognize
{
    if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer) // tapRecognizer is the first imageviews recognizer
    {
        if (tapRecognize.state == what should go here? 
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

What should go after `tapRecognize ==`?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tapRecognizerMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognize{
  if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer){
     if (tapRecognize.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
            UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView*)[tapRecognize view];
            //Now need to rotate the image
     }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the following link:
[rotating Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees#answer-1317194)

Comment: It doesn't work, I have tried with a NSLog where it should be rotated it but it doesnt log anything?

Comment: Please share your code of where you are logging and also where u add the tap-gesture on u r image.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognize
    {
        if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer)
        {
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(lineImage.transform, 90);
            [lineImage setTransform:transform];
        }
    }
```

and make sure you have enabled the uesr interaction of imageviews,

```
  [imageView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [imageView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually requires a flip rotation you better chose below swipe gestures.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[swipeLeft release];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
[swipeRight release];
```

On handler method you give an animation for separate flip right and left

```
if(isActiveFlipLeft)
{
[UIView transitionWithView:imageSnap
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    imageSnap.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:187.0/225.0 green:187.0/225.0 blue:187.0/225.0 alpha:1.0];
                    imageSnap.image = image;                        
} completion:NULL];}
else if (isActiveFlipRight)
{
[UIView transitionWithView:imageSnap
                          duration:1.0f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        animations:^{
                            imageSnap.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:187.0/225.0 green:187.0/225.0 blue:187.0/225.0 alpha:1.0];
                            imageSnap.image = image;                                
} completion:NULL];}
```

The below code is for just a simple tap gesture. you will get call on handleSingleTap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

[singleTap release];
```

Gesture handler

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

If you requires real rotation you can use

```
imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 270.0/180*M_PI );
```

something like in your gesture handler