# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo orientation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiimage

i'm trying to manage image rotation in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, but after several attempts, I did not find any solutions. My last try is:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

        // load the storyboard by name
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[ApplicationSupport getStoryBoardName] bundle:nil];
        UploadViewController *uploadView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewUploadFile"];

        UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSDictionary *metadataImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];

        uploadView.imageToUpload = image;

        if([[metadataImage objectForKey:@"Orientation"] intValue] == 3) {
            UIImage *imageRotated = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:[image scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
            uploadView.dataToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageRotated);
        } else {
            uploadView.dataToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        }

        // ETC...
    }
```

I can't and I don't want to use `JPEGRepresentation`. I need to rotate my photo by 180° when iPad is in specific position.

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried using UIImageOrientationLeft or UIImageOrientationRight instead of Dowm. does it rotate?

Comment: After several attemps, i understood that i don't want to change an orientation "flag". I need to "physically" rotate my image. So i tried this:
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, (90 * M_PI / 180));
        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        UIImage *imageRotated = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        uploadView.dataToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageRotated);`

But it return to me blank image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a Look at this: http://www.catamount.com/blog/1015/uiimage-extensions-for-cutting-scaling-and-rotating-uiimages/

Just call

```
UIImage *rotatedImage = [originalImage imageRotatedByDegrees:180.0];
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)

Comment: Man this is simply awesome, it works great! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

UploadView.DataToUpload = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation : UIImageOrientationDown];

For 180 deg rotation.