# Button changes orientation on touch catched. IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I had to animate few button in such a way that it looks like they are rotating onto screen from below and managed to do that. In order for the solution to work I needed to change buttons orientation on viewDidLoad like this:

```
for (UIButton* button in self.shareButtons) {
    button.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:button.imageView.image.CGImage
                                                 scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
}
```

It all works fine, but when a touch is catch within a button it then cancel this orientation change and button is "downmirrored" as caused by the animations.

How can I prevent/avoid it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the orientation of the image? Why are you not doing this with a (affine) transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the image this way

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:button.imageView.image.CGImage
                 scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

also have a look at my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413833/didfinishpickingmediawithinfo-orientation-issue/16415543?noredirect=1#comment23536769_16415543) for rotating images

as mentioned in comments Applying transform is also a good option

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 180 * M_PI ) / 180 );
```

will rotate the UIButton 180 degrees.