# how do i rotate a MKPolygon pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner programmer and this is my first app and am still learning, I overlayed a polygon onto a map view and it works but i set its fill color to an image because I'm trying to match an image to a satellite picture, i want to rotate it so that i can fit it on, is it possible to rotate the image, if not is there an easier way to overlay an image onto a map view

here is my code

```
-(MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay {

MKPolygonView *polyView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
polyView.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
polyView.fillColor = [UIColor  colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Campus-map labels.jpg"]];

return polyView;
}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees) shows how to rotate a UIImage.

Comment: that is an image view, i am not using a view I'm drawing it on the map, if i was using a UIImage i would use that but this is different i can show you if you like @68cherries

Comment: You are using a UIImage to set the `polyView.fillColor`'s pattern.  I think that rotating that image is what you are looking for if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes but im drawing a polygon on a map view then filling the drawn polygon with a pattern, @68cherries

Comment: Have you found a solution to this, by any chance?