# Rotate a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, uiimage

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate the image of an image view and determine the direction it is facing.

I know I can rotate the UIImageView like this

```
imagView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Rotate a UIImage 90 degrees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIImage *yourImageHere;
switch (imageView.image.imageOrientation)
{
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        newImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageView.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
        imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        newImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageView.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
        imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        newImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageView.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
        imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        newImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageView.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
imageView.image=newImage;
```

May this helps you