# ImageView rotating when using imagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uikit

I have a table view and in the cell, there is an image and 2 labels. I am using `imagePicker` to choose a photo from my camera roll and putting that photo into the cell image. However, when the photo is a portrait mode photo, the image is rotated 90 degrees.

In the code below, posting is an outlet that connects to the `imageview` in the table view cell and I initialized a `UIImagePickerController`.

```
class MakePostVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var postTitle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var postDescrip: UITextField!

var imgPicker: UIImagePickerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    postImg.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    postImg.clipsToBounds = true

    imgPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imgPicker.delegate = self

}
```

Here is my function for `didFinishPickingImage`:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    imgPicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    postImg.image = image
}
```

I've looked at similar posts here on SO but the solutions don't seem to work.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

#### Updated to Swift 5.3, iOS 14

Sunil Sharma's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141626/8160613) worked for me. Here is translated version to **Swift 5**

```swift
extension UIImage {
    var fixedOrientation: UIImage {
        guard imageOrientation != .up else { return self }
        
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
        switch imageOrientation {
        case .down, .downMirrored:
            transform = transform
                .translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height).rotated(by: .pi)
        case .left, .leftMirrored:
            transform = transform
                .translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0).rotated(by: .pi)
        case .right, .rightMirrored:
            transform = transform
                .translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height).rotated(by: -.pi/2)
        case .upMirrored:
            transform = transform
                .translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0).scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        default:
            break
        }
        
        guard
            let cgImage = cgImage,
            let colorSpace = cgImage.colorSpace,
            let context = CGContext(
                data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height),
                bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0,
                space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: cgImage.bitmapInfo.rawValue
            )
        else { return self }
        context.concatenate(transform)
        
        var rect: CGRect
        switch imageOrientation {
        case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
            rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.height, height: size.width)
        default:
            rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        }
        
        context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)
        return context.makeImage().map { UIImage(cgImage: $0) } ?? self
    }
}
```

Comment: One of those instances where you ask yourself ? Why is this necessary ... Anway, just copy pasted into my swiftui project and worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`UIImage` consists a property named `imageOrientation`.As this property is described in Apple documentation:

> Image orientation affects the way the image data is displayed when
>   drawn. By default, images are displayed in the “up” orientation. If
>   the image has associated metadata (such as EXIF information), however,
>   this property contains the orientation indicated by that metadata.

So this property is used to reflect the positioning of the camera with respect to the ground.So when you take an image from phone camera then it saves the orientation flag in `UIImage` `imageOrientation` property.

While displaying if this property is ignored then you may not find your image in the right orientation.Just for reference see image below how camera takes image and then encoded and displayed.Check this [link](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html) for more detail.
[image]

To fix this problem in ios
**Objective-C**

Make category

**UIImage+fixOrientation.h**

```
@interface UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation;

@end
```

**UIImage+fixOrientation.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}

@end
```

**Swift**

Make extension as

```
extension UIImage {

    func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {

        // No-op if the orientation is already correct
        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up ) {
            return self;
        }

        // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
        // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Down || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Left || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Right || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,  CGFloat(-M_PI_2));
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        }

        // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
        // calculated above.
        let ctx: CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(self.size.width), Int(self.size.height),
                                                      CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                                      CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                                      CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage).rawValue)!;

        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform)

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Left ||
            self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored ||
            self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Right ||
            self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored ) {
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage)
        } else {
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage)
        }

        // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context and return it
        return UIImage(CGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate image like this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1317194/3928412

also you need to get the device rotation, you can get it like:

```
 UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
```