# Swift how to prevent image being rotate and starch

Tags: swift

This function is supposed to take an image and convert it into data and from the data it will be converted back to image. when I used an image from an image library or when I take the photo in landscape mode it works fine. But when I take the photo in portrait mode the image will be rotated and stretched when its being converted back to an image. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

```
func pixelCalculator (){
    let image = originalImage

    let height = Int((image.size.height))
    print(height)
    let width = Int((image.size.width))

    let bitsPerComponent = Int(8)
    let bytesPerRow = 4 * width
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBAPixel>.allocate(capacity: (width * height))
    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
    let CGPointZero = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: (image.size))



    let imageContext = CGContext(data: rawData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

    imageContext?.draw(image.cgImage!, in: rect)

    let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<RGBAPixel>(start: rawData, count: width * height)

    let outContext = CGContext(data: pixels.baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,space: colorSpace,bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,releaseCallback: nil,releaseInfo: nil)

    let outImage = UIImage(cgImage: outContext!.makeImage()!)
    imageView.image = outImage

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing UIimages pulled from the Camera also ROTATES the UIimage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260249/resizing-uiimages-pulled-from-the-camera-also-rotates-the-uiimage)

Comment: Check this answer might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139850/imageview-rotating-when-using-imagepicker/38141626#38141626

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this `extension` to fix the orientation of image:

```
extension UIImage {
    func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {
        if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {
            return self
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        if let normalizedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return normalizedImage
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I use this extension:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        let fixedPickedImage = pickedImage.fixOrientation()//this is the new fixed orientation image.
    }
    parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

P.s:
You can change orientation type according to your requirements. Just change:

```
 if self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up {//change orientation
        return self
    }
```

These are all types of orientations explained in degrees,

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImageOrientation) {
        UIImageOrientationUp,            // default orientation
        UIImageOrientationDown,          // 180 deg rotation
        UIImageOrientationLeft,          // 90 deg CCW
        UIImageOrientationRight,         // 90 deg CW
        UIImageOrientationUpMirrored,    // as above but image mirrored along other axis. horizontal flip
        UIImageOrientationDownMirrored,  // horizontal flip
        UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored,  // vertical flip
        UIImageOrientationRightMirrored, // vertical flip
    };
```

You can refer [UIImage.Orientation Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/orientation) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In some `UIImage`s, its bitmap representation (`CGImage`) is rotated and `UIImage` draws it unrotated according to the `imageOrientation` property, which your code ignores.

You can write something like this:

```
func pixelCalculator() {
    let image = originalImage

    //### Keep scale and orientation.
    let scale = originalImage.scale
    let orientation = originalImage.imageOrientation

    let height = Int(image.size.height)
    let width = Int(image.size.width)

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerRow = 4 * width
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBAPixel>.allocate(capacity: (width * height))
    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: (image.size))

    let imageContext = CGContext(data: rawData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)

    imageContext?.draw(image.cgImage!, in: rect)

    let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<RGBAPixel>(start: rawData, count: width * height)

    let outContext = CGContext(data: pixels.baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,space: colorSpace,bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,releaseCallback: nil,releaseInfo: nil)

    //### Create a UIImage with the same scale and orientation as the originalImage.
    let outImage = UIImage(cgImage: outContext!.makeImage()!, scale: scale, orientation: orientation)
    imageView.image = outImage
}
```

But, if you want to modify `pixels` and your algorithm depends on orientation, better use something like Enea Dume's answer.