# Problems with cropping a UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, crop

I'm writing an app that takes an image and crops out everything except for a rectangle in the center of the image. (SWIFT) I can't get the crop function to work though. This is what I have now:

```
func cropImageToBars(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
     let crop = CGRectMake(0, 200, image.size.width, 50)

     let cgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, crop)
     let result: UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage!, scale: 0, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(result, self, nil, nil)

     return result
  }
```

I've looked at a lot of different guides but none of them seem to work for me. Sometimes the image is rotated 90 degrees, I have no idea why it does that.

Comment: Welcome to stack OverFlow. Before your question, please check what helpful on this site is available. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage/29294333#29294333

Comment: Looks like a similar question, but I'm having a problem with Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: And there are many solutions for swift as well. This looks the best: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30403863/661022

Comment: Thanks for answering. How do I implement an extension in Swift? I assume you just add it to the end of say, your main view controller class?

Comment: This question has more and better answer than the other. It would be fair to post "This question already has answers here:" in the other question.

Answer (score 29):

If you would like to use an extension, just simply add it to the file, in the beginning, or the end. You can create an extra file for such code.

**Swift 3.0**

```
extension UIImage {
    func crop( rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        var rect = rect
        rect.origin.x*=self.scale
        rect.origin.y*=self.scale
        rect.size.width*=self.scale
        rect.size.height*=self.scale

        let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        return image
    }
}


let myImage = UIImage(named: "Name")
myImage?.crop(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
```

for crop of a center portion of an image:

```
let imageWidth = 100.0
let imageHeight = 100.0
let width = 50.0
let height = 50.0
let origin = CGPoint(x: (imageWidth - width)/2, y: (imageHeight - height)/2)
let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

myImage?.crop(rect: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
```

Comment: I posted the example in latest Swift 3.0. In case you work in the older version, copy paste will require some corrections.

Comment: The cropping seems to work but I can't get it to crop the section of the image that I actually want. For example, arguments (50,50,500,500) returns a portion of the image from the top right of the screen, which makes no sense to me. If I want a rectangle in the middle of the screen (sort of like this http://imgur.com/a/vOMsb) what should the rectangle args be?

Comment: @KaviRamamurthy I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried it and it returns a rotated image. Any way to rotate it back?

Comment: I haven't tested. Rotated? Weird. Here you can rotate your image. But I am not sure if I understand you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38678800/661022

Comment: I have also struggled with this. The image only seems to be cropping its upper coordinates.

Comment: I believe I have the same problem @MehdiAbderezai has; After cropping, the image's center shifts to the top left.

Comment: What if the UIImage by chance does not contain a CGImage, and instead a CIImage?