# Take just a part of an UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uikit

It's a simple question but quite hard to achieve. 
How do I clips a UIImage, so that I have from a 600*400 image a 60*40 Image at the Position CGRect(x: 200, y: 350)?

Comment: [Cropping Images in Swift and the Basics of UIImage, CGImage and CIImage](https://medium.com/@joehattori/cropping-images-in-swift-and-the-basics-of-uiimage-cgimage-and-ciimage-42608e4531bb); [Problems with cropping a UIImage in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310729/problems-with-cropping-a-uiimage-in-swift); [Crop Image Gist](https://gist.github.com/Digitalchemy/813185); [MediaKit/UIImage+Crop.swift](https://github.com/wonderkiln/MediaKit/blob/master/MediaKit/UIImage%2BCrop.swift); [Image Crop](http://blogs.innovationm.com/image-croprotateresize-handling-in-ios/)