# Is [UIImage imageWithCIImage:scale:orientation] broken on iOS10?

Tags: ios, uiimage, ios10

The following code does no longer work on iOS10. The image data remains unrotated.

I have confirmed that this code works on iOS 8 and 9.

```
CIImage *i = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:i scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
```

Has anyone run into this same problem? Is this a bug, or an intended change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that something has changed in terms of how UIImageView handles image rotation flags. I can't find the changes mentioned anywhere, but at least the code below works. [Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30703714/37346).

```
- (UIImage*)rotateImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage clockwise:(BOOL)clockwise
{
    CGSize size = sourceImage.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(size.height, size.width));
    [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[sourceImage CGImage]
                         scale:1.0
                   orientation:clockwise ? UIImageOrientationRight : UIImageOrientationLeft]
     drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.height ,size.width)];

    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the CIImage's orientation, please try this.

```
let newCIImage: CIImage
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    newCIImage = myCIImage.oriented(.right)
} else {
    newCIImage = myCIImage.oriented(forExifOrientation: Int32(CGImagePropertyOrientation.right.rawValue))
}
```