# How to color an image?

Tags: iphone, colors, uiimage, uitabbar

I have a problem concerning an icon:

I have an icon (with transparency), which is black. For different uses I want to color it to blue (for example). Originally the icon was made to fit a UITabbar. There the color of the shape is colored to blue as well, when selected.
This is what I want to reach. Has anyone a possible solution?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117211/how-would-i-tint-an-image-programatically-on-the-iphone

Comment: Paul, the answer to that question is to use an overlay blend. I think a color blend is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do a color blend. My fork of [MGImageUtilities](https://github.com/kballard/MGImageUtilities) should provide what you want. It can take your black icon and color all the visible pixels blue without affecting the alpha channel.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. But there is only one problem. I can not blend my image to white (to use it in a UIBarbuttonItem). I don't know why, but your UIImage does only blend a thin border of the shape without affecting the fill color.

Comment: Ah, I know what your issue is. It's keeping the brightness of the original image while using the color that you specify. In other words, it's doing a real tint. You can either convert your image to be all white (or to have some actual brightness that means something), or you can use Matt Gemmell's [original version](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities), which ignores the brightness of the image.