# iPhone : How to use loop to generator a 256 color table in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, colors

I try to show 256 colors in iphone or even more colors

At first ,I use photoshop to generator some simple color png file

Than I add this png to an array and set it as a button picture

This is what I done now

This is the code how I add color into array

```
imgArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon0.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon1.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon2.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon3.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon4.png"],
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon5.png"],
                nil];
```

Than I add this to button image

This is the result on my simulator , but this is not a good solution

[image]

It waste too many time to add png file (also waste iphone memory...)

Does anyone can help me to figure this problem ???

MANY THANKS : )

Answer (score 6):

if you just want to simply showing colors, you can subclassing UIView and override `drawRect:`

code is something like this:

```
    CGFloat red, green, blue, x, y, width, height;
    for (red = 0; red < 1; red += 1/8)
    for (blue = 0; blue < 1; blue += 1/8)
    for (green = 0; green < 1; green += 1/8) {
    //update x and y
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1];  //create the color by rgb value
        [color setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x, y, width, height));  //draw the rect

    }
```

Comment: +1 this is a great answer.  The OP will want to read this guide by Apple on [Quartz 2D programming.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066)  This will help explain `drawRect:` and `CGContext` and it's methods.

Comment: I'm not just show the colors , It need to be show on a button

Comment: you may also override the touch handle method to check where does the user touch the view by using `locationInView:` in UITouch and use it to calculate what color in that pixel

Comment: a better way rather override the touch handle method is use UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: UIButton being a subclass of UIView has the property `backgroundColor`, you could create UIButtons programmatically and set their position and background colors

Comment: Thank you - you might need to replace 1/8 with 0.125 to get the proper float arithmetic happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could load only one black and white png and then tint the color of the image as shown in this question below...
[How would I tint an image programmatically on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117211/how-would-i-tint-an-image-programatically-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Well ... I don't know this link is help me or not...your solution is put another image on a black or white color background ...But the question is how to create 000000~FFFFFF color ???