# Applying blue color effect to a picture

Tags: iphone, ios4, filter

Can we apply some blue color effects to photo taken by iPhone or iPad programatically.

Like what we achieve using blend modes (eg. hue) using a blue color layer with any image in photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an article.

[How would I tint an image programmatically on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117211/how-would-i-tint-an-image-programatically-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of ready to use image manipulation routines like http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

or you could try to mess with UIImage