# XCode image colour overlay effect

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimageview

I am wondering if the following is possible and how to go about it.

I have an image (UIImageView) which is a png file with a transparent background. The image is all the same shade of grey (It is essentially a silhouette) and has 4 distinct segments.

Below the image I have a slider with 4 stops (inc start and end) - So when the user slides it 'snaps' so that the pointer is positioned directly beneath a 'segment' of the image.

What I would like to do is:
  If the slider is under segment 2 for example, the image will appear with a blue tint from a certain x position to another x position.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking here. Could you provide an example image of the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: Why not use four images and simulate the snapping you're talking about?

Comment: That would be too easy @Hyperbole :) I was hoping not to snap the colour overlay effect so it was a smooth transition over the 4 parts of the image

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to monitor the `UIControlEventValueChanged` on a `UISlider`.  You can set `slider.minimumValue = 0;` and `slider.maximumValue = 4;`.

Then in the action you set to `UIControlEventValueChanged` you can snap the slider to that location and change the tint. Ex:

```
- (void)valueChanged:(id)sender {
    if (value<0) {
         slider.value = 0;
         //Tint the uiimage
    }
    else if (value<1) {
         slider.value = 2;
         //Tint the uiimage
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have the slider function working fine. It's the manipulating the image part I am working on. Also, this is the code I amusing to 'snap' my slider `-(IBAction)valueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
    NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(slider.value + 0.5); // Round the number.
    [slider setValue:index animated:NO];`

Comment: You can use Core Graphics. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117211/how-would-i-tint-an-image-programatically-on-the-iphone